# Stop event bubbling - onclick listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-bubbling

Why clicking on parent `div` element does the job, but clicking on the child div text `Click Me!` returns `undefined` and the page doesn't load in iframe? I used `event.stopPropagation` to stop bubbling but it is still the same. What is the correct way to do that, when `addEvenLisneter` is preferred over inline `onclick` ?

```js
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

[].forEach.call(panel, function(each) {
    each.addEventListener('click', linkClick);
});

function linkClick ( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    iframe.src = event.target.dataset.url;
}
```

```css
.panel {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.panel div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp">
  <div>Click Me!</div>
</div>
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

When I `console.log(event)` bubble property is still set to true.

Comment: "but clicking on the text field" — What text field? There is no text field in your example. Provide a real [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I mean the text in the `div` `Click Me!`

Comment: But I stopped bubbling on parent div, if I understand bubbling correct it shouldn't look for `data-url` in child `div`.

Comment: hey, it's the bubble, no stone - bubble pops up!

Comment: So how can I stop the one that goes down to children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prevented the click event from bubbling from the inner div, then it would never reach the one to which you bound the event handler and your function would not fire at all.

The problem here is that `event.target` matches the element that was actually clicked on. You want [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) if you want to get the element that the event handler was bound to.

```js
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

[].forEach.call(panel, function(each) {
    each.addEventListener('click', linkClick);
});

function linkClick ( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    iframe.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.url;
}
```

```css
.panel {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.panel div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp">
  <div>Click Me!</div>
</div>
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Now, its not working totally, giving undefined all the time

Comment: Yeah, first I removed `dataset` too, so it didn't work. Now works fine thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am not actually solving the problem as a such, more like a workaround.

Maybe you could try using a button instead, as this is slightly more valid HTML.

I modified the CSS a bit, so it matches your example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.panel {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left
}

</style>
<body>

<button class="panel" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

</body>
<script>
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

[].forEach.call(panel, function(each) {
    each.addEventListener('click', linkClick);
});

function linkClick ( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    iframe.src = event.target.dataset.url;
}
</script>
</html>
```